# Health App ignoring Steps after some time

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am currently trying to write a simple workout app with swift in Xcode.
With the App I want to read and write data to and from the health app. So far I started with an easy first step: A dummy app for reading and writing step counts.

At first everything seems to work, my app asked for data access, it is listed as a source in the health app and I can read and write step counts.
So far so good.

But sometimes the steps that were added by my app get ignored after some time.
Let's say I had 8000 Steps today and added 2000 via my app, at first I would see 10000 steps in the health app and in all other apps that read the steps count. But then after some time the total steps count in the health app would drop back to 8000 (and all reading apps would read 8000 again). But then when I look into the health app and go into the "all data" section for the steps count, I could still find the 2000 steps from my app in the list. They just seem to be ignored when calculating the total steps per day.

Does apple only allow steps from "validated" sources or is there another reason why my steps are ignored after some time?

Answer (score 2):

If your app's step samples overlap with samples from other sources (like the iPhone or Apple Watch) then HealthKit may be preferring the overlapping samples. By default, HealthKit prefers samples from Apple Watch and iPhone. You can control which sources of samples are preferred, though, by going to the Health Data tab, and navigating to Activity > Steps > Data Sources & Access and then tapping the Edit button in the top right. You may then re-order the Data Sources section of the table.